# scale_x_discrete labels disappeared in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, scatter-plot

im new in R, and for some reason the values of X in my plot disappeared, ive found in many pages how to change it but not to set as default, i mean the values for fixed acidity. i have no idea how it was removed.

code:

```
ggplot(redwine, aes(x = fixed.acidity, y = density, col = quality)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete("Fixed Acidity") + scale_y_continuous("Density") +
  scale_color_continuous("Quality")
```

follow my data:

```
    redwine <- structure(list(fixed.acidity = c(7.4, 7.8, 7.8, 11.2, 7.4, 7.4
), volatile.acidity = c(0.7, 0.88, 0.76, 0.28, 0.7, 0.66), citric.acid = c(0, 
0, 0.04, 0.56, 0, 0), residual.sugar = c(1.9, 2.6, 2.3, 1.9, 
1.9, 1.8), chlorides = c(0.076, 0.098, 0.092, 0.075, 0.076, 0.075
), free.sulfur.dioxide = c(11, 25, 15, 17, 11, 13), total.sulfur.dioxide = c(34, 
67, 54, 60, 34, 40), density = c(0.9978, 0.9968, 0.997, 0.998, 
0.9978, 0.9978), pH = c(3.51, 3.2, 3.26, 3.16, 3.51, 3.51), sulphates = c(0.56, 
0.68, 0.65, 0.58, 0.56, 0.56), alcohol = c(9.4, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 
9.4, 9.4), quality = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("fixed.acidity", 
"volatile.acidity", "citric.acid", "residual.sugar", "chlorides", 
"free.sulfur.dioxide", "total.sulfur.dioxide", "density", "pH", 
"sulphates", "alcohol", "quality"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

tks

[image]

Comment: ggplot(redwine, aes(x = fixed.acidity, y = density, col = quality)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_discrete("Fixed Acidity") + 
  scale_y_continuous("Density") +    
  scale_color_continuous("Quality")

Comment: You're using `scale_x_discrete` to set the label, but that's not what it's designed for. You should use something like `+ labs(x = "Fixed Acidity")`. (And there are many other ways of setting the axis labels)

Comment: The [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/) is a good resource

Comment: thanks SymbolixAU. i understand what you mean, but i want the ticks and the values for Fixed Acidity back, would you know how to to that ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you removed the `scale_x_discrete` line?

Comment: i believe so. but i was trying to do few things and then i realised that ive changed this... how could i put the line back ?

Comment: I want to see the scale values for FIxed Acidity above the label, as i can see the values for DENSITY (i.e. 0.990, 0.995, 1.000), do you know what a mean ?

Comment: Yes I understand what you're after, but I don't understand why it's not working. It would be easier to understand if we could see your data too `dput(head(redwine))`

Comment: ive updated the question with the data. hope it helps.

Comment: use `ggplot(redwine, aes(x = fixed.acidity, y = density, col = quality)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Fixed Acidity", y = "Density", colour = "Quality")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mock example showing how to correctly set the labels and axis text

If all you want to do is set the axis labels, then the simplest way is to use the `labs` function

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
redwine <- data.frame(fixed.acidity = rnorm(n = 100),
                                            density = rnorm(n = 100),
                                            quality = rnorm(n = 100))

## replace the 'scale_x_discrete' with 'labs'
ggplot(redwine, aes(x = fixed.acidity, y = density, col = quality)) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = FALSE) +
    #scale_x_discrete("Fixed Acidity") + 
    #scale_y_continuous("Density") +
    labs(x = "Fixed Acidity", y = "Density") 
    #scale_color_continuous("Quality")
```

[image]

If you want to format the axis labels, you can do so in the `theme()` function

```
ggplot(redwine, aes(x = fixed.acidity, y = density, col = quality)) + 
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = FALSE) +
    labs(x = "Fixed Acidity", y = "Density") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: you can put  `colour` in `labs()` as well

Comment: no worries. I recommend going through various `ggplot` resources to fully understand what the `scale_x_xxx` functions do